# Android device: unable to access /proc/[PID]/status

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I'm not able to access `/proc/[pid]/status` file. It gives error:

```
avc: denied { read } for name="/" dev="dm-0" ino=2 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c217,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:rootfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

I think I need to add `uses_permission` tag in the android app manifest file, to give the app permission to access that location. But I don't know which permission I should add to get this working.
I tried adding this and did not work.

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Would need some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

> avc: denied { read } for name="/" dev="dm-0" ino=2 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c217,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:rootfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0

This is a prompt from SELinux. The app process is no longer allowed to read other PID information in the higher version of Android.

You have two solutions:

1. If you have root permission, "setenforce 0" through the shell and run the program again.
2. If you have Android system source code, customize the relevant sepolicy permissions, and allow the app process to read other PID information.

Comment: root permission is not an option for me. Can u elaborate on the 2nd point? I have the source code for the app I m developing. not sure what u meant by "Android System source Code" .Also by "relevant sepolicy permission" u meant uses_permission tag u put in manifest file? if so, which permission to use and how do I use it? How do I allow app process to read PID information?? TIA